# Testing a button with a method callback in a functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to test a react component using Enzyme. I am not able to test the click on the IconButton component and the function doesn't get called when i simulate a click.

This is how IconButton is defined on an external component.

```
var IconButton = function (props) {
    return (React.createElement(IconButton$1, { color: 'default', onClick: props.onClick, disabled: props.disabled, size: props.size, onMouseDown: props.onMouseDown }, props.children));
};export{Button,IconButton};
```

This is how I am using it in my app.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { Drawer } from '@material-ui/core';
import ExpandLessIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandLess';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';
import { IconButton } from '@mycomponent/button';

export default function Component1 {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(true);

  const handleClick = function (event) {
    if (event) {
      setOpen(!open);
    }
    else {
      return;
    }
  };

  return (
    <Drawer>
      <div className="classname1">
          <IconButton onClick={(e) => handleClick(e)} className={classes.button, "iconBtn"}>
            {open ? <ExpandLessIcon data-test="lessIcon" /> : <ExpandMoreIcon data-test="moreIcon" />}
          </IconButton>
      </div>
    </Drawer>
  );
}
```

Here is my test for simulating the click on the Icon Button. I also tried another way to check that the handleClick was getting called but it still fails.

```
    const wrapper = shallow(<Component1 />);

    it('Test the button click', () => {
        expect(wrapper.containsMatchingElement(<ExpandMoreIcon />)).toBeTruthy()
        const element = wrapper.find(".iconBtn")
        const mockEvent = {target: {}};
        element.simulate('click', mockEvent)
        expect(wrapper.containsMatchingElement(<ExpandLessIcon />)).toBeTruthy()
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line:

```
const element = wrapper.find("button").at(0);
```

or you could find it by it's className from `debug()`:

```
const element = wrapper.find(".MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root");
```

Notice that you'd simulate a click on an actual html button in such case.

Comment: It doesn't find any node now. "Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead."

Comment: So simulate a click on whatever this library you're using is rendering 'under the hood' of this `IconButton$1`

Comment: So it's certainly a `button`, you can always investigate a component with by `console.log(wrapper.debug())`

Comment: <IconButton onClick={[Function: onClick]} className="iconBtn" name="false">
              <ExpandMoreIcon data-test="moreIcon" />
            </IconButton>

Comment: I've dited my answer

Comment: Got it! Thank a lot. So I was able to simulate the click on the button from the mount wrapper. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226678/discussion-between-cody-kc-and-k-wasilewski).